# How to find the First Responder for undo:, redo: menu options?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

I am trying to use validateMenuItem to temporary disable undo and redo in the user menu. I am doing this to prevent too fast, repeated undos when cloud actions are being undone.

I have tried putting the validateMenuItem method in every class that was mentioned in the responder chain, namely NSView, NSViewController, NSTableView, NSWindowController, AppDelegate, or rather their subclasses. However, the only menu items that I get there are the custom ones, the ones that I made.

The standard methods, such as undo, redo, cut, copy and so on never show up.

Is there another possibility, where could the first responder for these be?

Comment: Read [Undo and the Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/AppKitUndo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000213-74028)

Comment: So I did. Still don't have a clue.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the first responder is. The question is "How can I intercept the Undo and Redo menu commands?". Do you use Core Data or `NSDocument`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do but the only place that I found to do that was validateMenuItem, which does seem to be related to the first responder. Actually, I only use undoManager!.registerUndoWithTarget, and not CoreData nor NSDocument. (I mean, I do use coredata in the project only not its undo manager directly)

Comment: Did you try `validateMenuItem` in a subclass of `NSWindow`?

Comment: I did just now but still no sign of undo/redo.

Comment: `validateMenuItem` in a subclass of `NSWindow` works in my simple test app. Which object in the responder chain provides the undo manager?

Comment: ViewController. I just use the do registerUndoWithTarget on the provided undoManager. (I think it's just inherited from NSResponder)

Comment: The first object in the responder chain which implements the action of the menu item will get the `validateMenuItem` message. If you want the view controller to get the undo `validateMenuItem` message, implement `undo:`.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot - this was all that was required - it works now perfectly.